# How to parse information from children tag using beautifulsoup from xml file?

Tags: python, xml, parsing, beautifulsoup, children

Here is the layout of the XML file that I am parsing. Whenever an instance occurs when there is a tag like driverslicense with multiple values I am trying to parse them to get the name and text. i.e. {number: 99999999, state: CA}

```
 """ >  <subjects>

        <subject id="B6">

            <name type="primary">

                <first>Frank </first>

                <middle></middle>

                <last>Darko</last>

            </name>

            <birthdate>10/26/2001</birthdate>

            <age>17</age>

            <ssn>12345679</ssn>

            <description>

                <sex>Male</sex>

            </description>

            <address type="residence" ref="A1"/>

            <driverslicense state="CA" number="99999999"/>

        </subject>

    </subjects>"""
```

My code is as follows:

```
dl = bs_data.find("driverslicense")
```

Output:

```
<driverslicense number="T64430698" state="VA"/>
```

I tried do a for loop but then no value is returned as well as .text but this also returns none.

```
for i in bs_data.find('driverslicense'):
print(i)
------------------
DriverLicense = bs_data.find("driverslicense")
print(DriverLicense.text)
```

I prefer to get this in dictionary form but if I get this as independent variables like state = CA and number = 99999999 that would work as well.

Comment: `state` and `number` are attributes of `driverslicense` while you are trying `text`

Comment: I am new to parsing so was just working with different ideas that I thought would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just in addition if you like to get a `dict` with the `attributes` and values of a `tag` you could simply call `.attrs`.

```
soup.select_one('driverslicense').attrs
```

**Note:** *In this case it works like charm, in others where you have to pick only specific attributes, the approache from @platipus_on_fire would be ideal or you might have to ignore or drop additional ones*

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<subjects>
    <subject id="B6">
        <name type="primary">
            <first>Frank </first>
            <middle></middle>
            <last>Darko</last>
        </name>
        <birthdate>10/26/2001</birthdate>
        <age>17</age>
        <ssn>12345679</ssn>
        <description>
            <sex>Male</sex>
        </description>
        <address type="residence" ref="A1"/>
        <driverslicense state="CA" number="99999999"/>
    </subject>
</subjects>
'''
soup.select_one('driverslicense').attrs
```

##### Output

```
{'state': 'CA', 'number': '99999999'}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way you can get that info:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = '''
<subjects>

        <subject id="B6">

            <name type="primary">

                <first>Frank </first>

                <middle></middle>

                <last>Darko</last>

            </name>

            <birthdate>10/26/2001</birthdate>

            <age>17</age>

            <ssn>12345679</ssn>

            <description>

                <sex>Male</sex>

            </description>

            <address type="residence" ref="A1"/>

            <driverslicense state="CA" number="99999999"/>

        </subject>

    </subjects>
'''
dict_with_stuff = {}
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
dict_with_stuff['state'] = soup.select_one('driverslicense').get('state')
dict_with_stuff['number'] = soup.select_one('driverslicense').get('number')
print(dict_with_stuff)
```

Result:

```
{'state': 'CA', 'number': '99999999'}
```

BeautifulSoup docs: https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html

Comment: Can't upvote this but this worked. I will have to break down the logic to fully understand this. Thanks @platipus_on_fire